What GPU should I buy for my new gaming PC?
I’m building my first pc and I’m going to use it for some gaming and Computer Assisted Design, my monitor supports 1440p and I want something that can handle games like call of duty and warthunder well

Can you share some more info to help us narrow it down? What is your budget? What is your current power supply wattage? Is there room in your PC case for a triple slot card? What is the max length that fits in your case? What country/currency are you shopping in? Do you need a recommendation that is available at a local retailer?

https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/
look at the scores and pricing, and then decide how much you want to spend for performance.  obviously more expensive = better card.
The general price point was in the ~$300 range for a good graphics card, I think that is now the ~$700 range, relatively speaking.
depends on the games and what they support, but I have experienced that if you have a 4K monitor (3840x2160) and want to run games at that resolution, have as much graphics card ram as you can.  4gb is not enough, you want at least 8gb and preferably 12gb and above now for what the newest games are capable of.
If you want to be really smart then identify specifically the game(s) you will be running and what gpu's those games favor in terms of nvidia vs AMD and so on.
And obviously double check your rig and power supply will physically support such a card.
For CAD there has never been an issue with using Nvidia GEforce consumer gpu's versus the commercial Quadro line; you definitely want geforce if you want any sort of gaming.  I can't speak to AMD's support regarding CAD.  Double check with your CAD software as to its graphics card requirements & preferences.
